# TypeError: Cannot read property 'go' of undefined with injected $state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

i already checked on stackoverflow and i see there are duplicate posts, but none of them resolved my issue. The issue with most of the cases is the injection of the $state. But i already injected in my controller above and still having the same issue.

My code:
App.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', [
    'wizardControllers',
    'claimDataService',
    'ui.router'
]);

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    // Otherwise
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/flight-details");
    $stateProvider

    .state('flight-details', {
        url: "/flight-details",
        controller: 'FlightDetailsController',
        templateUrl: "partials/flight-details.html"
     })
    .state('flight-problem', {
        url: "/flight-problem",
        controller: 'FlightProblemController',
        templateUrl: "partials/flight-problem.html"
     }) 

});
```

Controller:

```
var wizardControllers = angular.module('wizardControllers', ['ngAnimate']);

wizardControllers.controller('FlightDetailsController', ['$scope','$state','$http','claimDataService', function ($scope,$state,$http,claimDataService){

    $scope.claim = {};   
    $scope.claim_data = claimDataService.get();

    $scope.nextStep = nextStep;




    function nextStep(){
        claimDataService.set($scope.claim);

        $scope.$state.go("flight-problem");//Giving Me the error
    }

}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `$scope` before `$state`, try this

```
$state.go("flight-problem");//Working fine
```